# How to calculate the time difference using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner in VBA. I need solution to my problem only in VBA. Thanks.

Following are the tasks that I am required to do

1. Select a 'ID' and a 'Course' from the table. In the table below I have mentioned few IDs and Courses, however my project has multiple ID's and Courses. I cannot keep entering the ID and course name for all the cases. Is there a smart way to do this?
2. For a specific ID, Specific course and specific Date, I need to calculate the time difference between two rows as given in below table for specific 'Event'. The time difference first two rows give the time spent on 'Reading', the difference between row 2 and 3 give the time spent on 'Writing', the difference between row 3 and 4 give the time spent on 'Writing', and so on.

Any help will be highly appreciated. **The data format is in the link below**

[image]

Comment: I just launched a query on this site, using keywords "vba time difference" and I came up with 485 results. Isn't there anything there you can use?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the code and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim strID As String, strCourse As String, strEvent As String
    Dim DateTime1 As Date, DateTime2 As Date
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, y As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRow

            strID = .Range("A" & i).Value
            strCourse = .Range("B" & i).Value
            DateTime1 = CDate(.Range("C" & i).Value) & " " & CDate(.Range("D" & i).Value)
            strEvent = .Range("E" & i).Value

            For y = 2 To LastRow

                If y <> i Then

                    If .Range("A" & y).Value = strID And .Range("B" & y).Value = strCourse And .Range("E" & y).Value = strEvent And .Range("F" & i).Value = "" And .Range("F" & y).Value = "" Then
                        DateTime2 = CDate(.Range("C" & y).Value) & " " & CDate(.Range("D" & y).Value)
                         .Range("F" & i).Value = Abs(DateDiff("h", DateTime2, DateTime1))
                    End If

                End If

            Next y

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```